# How do i make a string of a recurve bow behave in a realistic way?

Tags: rigging, bones

I made a rig for my recurve bow using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVhFsR_TR7M

The problem is that when i pull far enough the string should follow and stop sticking to the bow. I don't know how to do that.

[image]
[image]
[image: Bow in a resting position]
Bow in a resting position
[image]
[image]
Here the string should follow to not look like its glued to the bow.